# No Video Output with DVI to VGA converter

Tags: xorg, x11, xrandr

Here's a weird one... so X definitely grabbed all the EDID info from my second monitor, as nothing seems amiss in any output or log. The system responds correctly to enabling output, i.e. xrandr displays all the correct info, emits no errors when enabling or disabling output to the DVI connection, and even lets my mouse fly to the left when I create a Xinerama screen.

However, all I actually get on my second monitor (connected with a DVI to VGA converter) is a black screen. Any idea how I can even begin troubleshooting that one? (it works fine on with winblows)...

Comment: If you swap your two monitors, is it still the left screen that's dead?